# Question about one issue in the proof of $\operatorname{Var}(Y^TAY)$

Tags: statistics, expected-value

Assume that $Y\sim \mathcal{N}(0,I)$. I have one question about the proof which shows that $\mathbb{Var}(Y^TAY)=2\operatorname{tr}(A^2)$. I will not show the whole proof here, because it's quite long.
Anyway, at the end of the proof we have

> $\mathbb{E}(Y^TAY)^2=3\sum\limits_{i} a_{ii}^2+\sum\limits_{i}\sum\limits_{k\neq i} a_{ii}a_{kk}+\sum\limits_{i}\sum\limits_{j\neq i} a_{ij}^2+ \sum\limits_{i}\sum\limits_{j\neq i}a_{ij}a_{ji}$ 
> If $A$ is symmetric, then $\operatorname{tr}(A^2)=\sum\limits_{i,j}a_{ij}^2$, so
> $$\mathbb{E}(Y^TAY)^2=(\operatorname{tr}(A))^2+2\operatorname{tr}(A^2).$$

I have two questions.

a) Why have they assumed that matrix $A$ is symmetric?

b) How have they obtained $\mathbb{E}(Y^TAY)^2=(\operatorname{tr}(A))^2+2\operatorname{tr}(A^2)$? I don't see here any connection with $\mathbb{E}(Y^TAY)^2=3\sum\limits_{i} a_{ii}^2+\sum\limits_{i}\sum\limits_{k\neq i} a_{ii}a_{kk}+\sum\limits_{i}\sum\limits_{j\neq i} a_{ij}^2+ \sum\limits_{i}\sum\limits_{j\neq i}a_{ij}a_{ji}$ (there should be).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are showing calculation for $\mathbb{E}(Y^TAY)^2$, where $A$ is assumed symmetric. The expectation of $Y^TAY$ requires no such assumption.

Comment: @StubbornAtom I have also thought that it does not require such assumption, but I do not know why they have done that this way. The aim is to calculate variance of $Y^TAY$. I haven't found different proof for showing that.

Comment: They are assuming $A$ is symmetric for finding $\mathbb{E}(Y^TAY)^2$ and hence the variance. Is your question about $\mathbb{E}(Y^TAY)$ or $\mathbb{E}(Y^TAY)^2$?

Comment: @StubbornAtom thanks. I have made a mistake in the post, see edited.

Comment: Hint: if $A_\pm:=(A\pm A^T)/2$ so $A_+$ ($A_-$) is symmetric (antisymmetric), how does $Y^TAY$ simplify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\def\tr\operatorname{tr}$
For the first question I don't know the precise answer.

For your second question, $A$ is symmetric, so $a_{ij}=a_{ji}$ for all $i\ne j$.
Let's calculate $\operatorname{tr}(A)^2$.
$$
\operatorname{tr}(A)^2=(\sum_i a_{ii})^2=\sum_{i,k}a_{ii}a_{kk}=\sum_i a_{ii}^2+\sum_{i}\sum_{k\ne i}a_{ii} a_{kk}.
$$
Next, we calculate $\operatorname{tr}(A^2)$
\begin{align}
\operatorname{tr}(A^2)=\sum_i(A^2)_{ii}=\sum_{i,j} a_{ij}a_{ji}=\sum_{i,j} a_{ij}^2.
\end{align}
Now, it's easy to see that
$$\mathbb{E}(Y^TAY)^2=(\operatorname{tr}(A))^2+2\operatorname{tr}(A^2).$$

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see it still. We have $\mathbb{E}(Y^TAY)^2=(\operatorname{tr}(A))^2+2\operatorname{tr}(A^2)=\sum\limits_ia_{ii}^2+\sum\limits_i \sum\limits_{k \neq i}a_{ii}a_{kk}+2\sum\limits_{i,j\neq i }a_{ij}^2$. It doesn't seem to be equal to what I ought to show, because we have $2\sum\limits_i a_{ii}^2$ left (looking at my proof). Where am I wrong?

Comment: Observe that in the last sum $j$ runs all values, $j$ can be equal to $i$.

Comment: Now everything is clear.